# What is the maximum stabilizer weight for Manfrotto Element Traveller tripod?

Tags: tripod, weight, manfrotto

What is the maximum stabilizer weight you can attach to the hook on the central column of the [Manfrotto Element Traveller](https://www.manfrotto.co.uk/element-traveller-tripod-big-with-ball-head-red) stand?

In the specs it says "Safety Payload Weight: 8 kg" but I assume that refers to the maximum weight of the camera ("payload"), rather than the stabilizer weight. I'm happy with an estimated range, e.g. ~1kg, ~10kg, 
~30kg, etc. My previous stand's plastic hook got broke when I attached ~10kg. I don't want to bend the stand legs either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My personal calculations (based on my degree of mechanical engineering):

Safety ratio `1.5` (avg) which mean tripod can handle `1.5*8kg=12kg`. Your camera+lens+accessories attached to camera and lens = (for example) `4kg`. So you can attach maximum of

```
12kg-4kg=8kg
```

And again: this is my personal calculation which is not based on any documentation from the manufacturer!!!

Answer (score 1):

**Payload is anything that isn't tripod.** Camera + lens + flash + stabilizer weight + anything else you might want to attach.

While the tripod itself should be able to hold 8kg (or 12kg, if you consider the safety ratio [Romeo Ninov describes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/108365/75526)), the hook attached to it may not. You will have to make a judgment call based on the apparent quality of the hook.

Consider starting with lighter weights and gradually increasing. Also consider putting sandbags around the legs, since hanging weights aren't necessarily "stable".

Comment: Thanks! Thanks for the tip concerning Sandbags! Actually I am already using a tight rope fixed to the my heavy weight instead of a hanging weight. And my small crane scale is on the way so I don't pull the rope too tight. I'm trying to have a stable tripod using low budget, all tips are appreciated!